# MySQL: Variable 'general_log_file' can't be set to the value of '~/path/to/new/file'

Tags: mysql, sql

I want MySQL to create a new general log file and log everything to it.

When I type this into MySQL:

```
set global general_log_file='~/path/to/new/file';
```

and the file is one that I want MySQL to create upon handling some transactions after I've set the global variable (i.e. it doesn't exist yet), it gives me an error:

```
Variable 'general_log_file' can't be set to the value of '~/path/to/new/file'
```

However, if I do it with a filepath that looks like:

```
set global general_log_file='new/file';
```

it doesn't complain and assigns the variable accordingly, even though this new file doesn't exist yet either.

What's going on here?

Comment: The translation of `~` to your home directory is done by the shell. MySQL doesn't know about that that naming convention.

Comment: How can I refer to my home directory within MySQL then?

Comment: Use the actual path, `/home/yourUsername`

Comment: See also https://serverfault.com/questions/506278/variable-general-log-file-cant-be-set-to-the-value-of-var-lib-msyql-ubuntu, but in addition, I suspect your home folder may not have the right permissions for the `mysqld` process to write to it.

Answer (score 1):

change my cnf.ini

```
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/new_file.log
general_log             = 1
```

Then restart the mysql process

> Server restarts and log flushing do not cause a new general query log
>   file to be generated (although flushing closes and reopens it)

```
shell> mysqladmin flush-logs
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
SET GLOBAL general_log_file='/var/log/general_log/general.log'; 

If error occurs MySQL: Variable 'general_log_file' can't be set to the value of '/var/log/general_log/general.log'

Just simple change file owner to mysql
Example chown -p mysql:mysql /var/log/general_log

Then change file permission
Format: chown 777 <log_output_file_name>
Ex: chmod 777 general.log

After that execute, 
SET GLOBAL general_log_file='/var/log/general_log/general.log'; 


Verify the result: show global variables like '%general_log_file%';


Output:
MariaDB [(none)]> show global variables like '%general_log_file%';

+------------------+----------------------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                            |
+------------------+----------------------------------+
| general_log_file | /var/log/general_log/general.log |
+------------------+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```